# Python Popen().stdout.read() hang

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, popen, freeze

I'm trying to get output of another script, using Python's `subprocess.Popen` like follows

```
process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
exitcode = process.wait()
output = process.stdout.read()   # hangs here
```

It hangs at the third line, only when I run it as a python script and I cannot reproduce this in the python shell.

The other script prints just a few words and I am assuming that it's not a buffer issue.

Does anyone has idea about what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: And if you run the command in `command` manually, it generates output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use [`.communicate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) rather than `.wait()` plus `.read()`. Note the warning about `wait()` on the `subprocess` documentation page:

> Warning This will deadlock when using `stdout=PIPE` and/or `stderr=PIPE` and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use `communicate()` to avoid that.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just realized I have read that part of the docs.. What I was doing was fetching the stdout real-time in a `while process.poll() is None:` loop while the script is running, and the code above was a stripped down version. But I guess it was hanging because of a similar deadlock issue ...

Comment: hmm this didn't work for me, it still hangs

Answer (score 0):

read() waits for EOF before returning.

You can:

- wait for the subprocess to die, then read() will return.
- use readline() if your output is broken into lines (will still hang if no output lines).
- use os.read(F,N) which returns at most N bytes from F, but will still block if the pipe is empty (unless O_NONBLOCK is set on the fd).

Answer (score -1):

You can see how to deal with hanging reading of stdout/stderr in the next sources:

[readingproc](https://github.com/sergzach/readingproc/)